# Deleting multiple rows from my DataGridView leaves 1 behind

Tags: c#, datagrid, datagridview

```
List<DataGridViewRow> rowsToDelete = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = row.Cells[0] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(chk.Value) == true)
        rowsToDelete.Add(row);
}
//loop through the list to delete rows added to list<T>:
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rowsToDelete)
        dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
```

I select 3 items and it deletes 2 but leaves 1 behind.

How do we fix it?

Comment: Your posted code works.  Everything I check gets deleted.

Comment: The last item I check is left behind. I select 3 items and 2 of them are removed. Last one is checked but not removed

Comment: ...and I do not get the same results with your code.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**

It sounds like you want to delete the non-checked items.

What you are going to have to do is start at the bottom and go to the top, otherwise you will have extra items left over.

Example:

```
for (int i = DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count - 1; -1 < i; i--)
{
   object objChecked = DataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value;
   if ((objChecked  != null) && !(bool)objChecked)
   {
     DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
   }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Based on your comments below, this version looks at `Rows` instead of `SelectedRows`.

Check that `Rows` exist before beginning your loop:

```
if ((0 < DataGridView1.Rows.Count) && (0 < DataGridView1.Columns.Count)) 
{
  for (int i = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; -1 < i; i--)
  {
    var row = DataGridView1.Rows[i];
    if ((row.Cells[0].Value != null) && (row.Cells[0].Value != DBNull.Value))
    {
      bool isChecked = (bool)row.Cells[0].Value;
      if (isChecked)
      {
        DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It is a little more robust in its error checking, and removes the row by reference instead of by its index.

Comment: I don't want the "SelectedRows". I want the rows that are not checked (which is Column 0 of every row). I want to retain the rows with the checkmark.

Comment: @CocoaDev You want to retain the rows with the checkmark?  Your code does the exact opposite.

Comment: once i get it working one way, I can do the inverse to get the opposite. Right now its not working with the checkbox present. To do the opposite, I can search for those checkboxes that are NOT selected.

Comment: Ah! You are going to have to start at the bottom and work your way up. See updated code.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. The dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt never executes. I think its because of "SelectedRows". Isn't selectedrows when you CTRL+CLICK multiple rows? What if no rows are selected but they are checked. How can we check for all rows that are checkmarked?

Comment: forgot to mention when I change the forloop to be "for (int i = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; -1 < i; i--)", I get an ArguementOutOfRangeException

Comment: OK, so you don't need `SelectedRows` at all. Try checking your Cell Values for `DBNull.Value` in addition to deleting the checked `Rows` "by reference" (?) instead of their index.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

You can delete by SelectedRows property.

Make sure that the `MultiSelect` property is set to true on your datagrid.

Then, you can utilize the `SelectedRows` property in the event of your choice:

*This is what you need, try this code :*

```
for (int i = dataGridView1.Rows.Count -1; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    if ((bool)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FormattedValue)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

OR

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

Comment: SelectedRows is rows that are highlighted. I want to get the rows that have a checkmark in the checkbox (which is COlumn 0 of every row)

Answer (score 0):

ASPXPAGE:

```
<strong>Asp.Net : Delete Multiple Records form datagridview in one time<br />
        </strong>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px"
            CellPadding="4" EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="Black">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="Sr No" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="doc_name" HeaderText="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="doc_add" HeaderText="Address" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="doc_mob" HeaderText="Mobile No" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="doc_email" HeaderText="Email" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Font-Size="12pt"
            onclick="Button1_Click1" Text="Delete" />
        <br />
```

Code Behind Page:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"server=server-pc; database=HMS; integrated security=true");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            load_data();
        }
    }

   public void load_data()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from doc_master", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
   protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       CheckBox ch;
       for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
       {
           ch = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Controls[1];
           if (ch.Checked == true)
           {
      int id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text);
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from doc_master where ID=" + id + " ", conn);
      conn.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      conn.Close();
           }
       }

       load_data();
   }
```

for detailed code visit::
http://www.gtuguide.com/2014/05/deleting-multiple-rows-in-gridview.html